# Remove inner brackets

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have the result

```
{{Position, {Code}}, 
 {1, {0000, 0001}}, 
 {2, {0100, 0011}}, 
 {3, {0110, 0111}}, 
 {4, {1000, 1001}}, 
 {5, {1100,1011}}, 
 {6, {1110, 1111}}}
```

and I want it to be

```
{{Position, Code}, 
 {1, 0000, 0001}, 
 {2, 0100, 0011}, 
 {3, 0110, 0111}, 
 {4, 1000, 1001},
 {5, 1100, 1011}, 
 {6, 1110, 1111}}
```

I tried

```
//.{x_,{y_}}:> {x,y}
```

but that seems to work only for the first element.

Any help would be appreciated Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

```
list // Map[Flatten]
```

> {{Position, Code}, {1, 0, 1}, {2, 100, 11}, {3, 110, 111}, {4, 1000,
> 1001}, {5, 1100, 1011}, {6, 1110, 1111}}

Comment: That's an original alternative to the – more common, I presume – `Flatten /@`.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
list={{Position,{Code}},{1,{0000,0001}},{2,{0100,0011}},{3,{0110,0111}},{4,{1000,1001}},{5,{1100,1011}},{6,{1110,1111}}} 

list /. {a_ ,  b_List } -> Join[{a}, b]
```

Answer (score 6):

A few additional methods:

```
Level[#, {-1}] & /@ list

Apply[Sequence, list, {-2}]

Map[Splice, list, {-2}]

Join[{#}, #2] & @@@ list

Prepend[#2, #]& @@@ list

MapAt[Splice, {All, 2}] @ list

ReplacePart[{_, 2, 0} -> Sequence] @ list

Map[Map @ Apply @ Sequence] @ list

Delete[{2, 0}] /@ list

FlattenAt[#, 2] & /@ list
```

... and for the Halloween:

[image]

```
☺ = ## & @@@ # & /@ # &;

☺ @ list
```

> ```
> {{Position, Code}, {1, 0, 1}, {2, 100, 11}, {3, 110, 111}, {4, 1000, 1001}, 
> {5, 1100, 1011}, {6, 1110, 1111}}
> ```

[image]

```
☺☺ = {#, ## & @@ #2} & @@@ # &;

☺☺ @ list
```

> ```
> {{Position, Code}, {1, 0, 1}, {2, 100, 11}, {3, 110, 111}, {4, 1000, 1001}, 
> {5, 1100, 1011}, {6, 1110, 1111}}
> ```

Comment: A little explanation: `## & @@@ # &` nearly == `Flatten` , a nice trick ;) . So the first 'riddle' == Flatten /@ list.

Comment: Showing off, but still a... Wow!

Answer (score 6):

You were *really* close.  You just need to add another underscore to `y_` as

```
list = {
 {Position, {Code}}, 
 {1, {0000, 0001}}, 
 {2, {0100, 0011}}, 
 {3, {0110, 0111}}, 
 {4, {1000, 1001}}, 
 {5, {1100,1011}}, 
 {6, {1110, 1111}}
};

list /. {x_, {y__}} :> {x, y}
```

> {{Position, Code},
> {1, 0000, 0001},
> {2, 0100, 0011},
> {3, 0110, 0111},
> {4, 1000, 1001},
> {5, 1100, 1011},
> {6, 1110, 1111}}

Answer (score 5):

`ReplacePart` can do it.

```
data = 
  {{Position, {Code}}, 
   {1, {0000, 0001}}, {2, {0100, 0011}}, {3, {0110, 0111}}, 
   {4, {1000, 1001}}, {5, {1100, 1011}}, {6, {1110, 1111}}};
ReplacePart[data, {i_, 2} :> Sequence @@ data[[i, 2]]]
```

> ```
> {{Position, Code},
>  {1, 0, 1}, {2, 100, 11}, {3, 110, 111}, 
>  {4, 1000, 1001}, {5, 1100, 1011}, {6, 1110, 1111}}
> ```