# Manipulating a list while maintaining the nested list structure

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a list of pairs of complex numbers with nesting as follows

```
{
{{1.91885 + 0.09170475 I, 1.91901 + 0.0629745061 I},
 {1.91837 + 0.092182 I, 1.9189 + 0.063 I},
 {1.9837 + 0.2182 I, 1.99 + 0.063 I},
 {1.91837 + 0.0921 I, 1.89 + 0.3 I}},
 {{1.91 + 0.091 I, 1.91 + 0.062974 I},
  {1.918 + 0.092 I, 1.89 + 0.63 I},
  {1.915 + 0.0915 I, 1.9191 + 0.05061 I}
 }
}
```

In reality, the list I am working with has many more sublists (here I've just shown two) and many more elements in each sublist.

I am trying to extract the second component of each pair of complex numbers while maintaining the nesting so here the expected output would be

```
{{1.91901 + 0.0629745061 I, 1.9189 + 0.063 I, 1.99 + 0.063 I,1.89 + 0.3 I},
 {1.91 + 0.062974 I, 1.89 + 0.63 I,  1.9191 + 0.05061 I}}
```

I have tried defining a function `sec[z_]:=Part[z,2]` and using `Map` or `Apply` to get what I want but this doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Closely related [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/233206/3066)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
lst = {{{1.91885 + 0.09170475 I, 
    1.91901 + 0.0629745061 I}, {1.91837 + 0.092182 I, 
    1.9189 + 0.063 I}, {1.9837 + 0.2182 I, 
    1.99 + 0.063 I}, {1.91837 + 0.0921 I, 
    1.89 + 0.3 I}}, {{1.91 + 0.091 I, 
    1.91 + 0.062974 I}, {1.918 + 0.092 I, 
    1.89 + 0.63 I}, {1.915 + 0.0915 I, 1.9191 + 0.05061 I}}};

Map[ReplaceAll[#, {x_, y_} -> y] &, lst]

(*  {{1.91901 + 0.0629745 I, 1.9189 + 0.063 I, 1.99 + 0.063 I, 
  1.89 + 0.3 I}, {1.91 + 0.062974 I, 1.89 + 0.63 I, 
  1.9191 + 0.05061 I}}   *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks Alexei! I always forget about using `ReplaceAll`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is simpler way to do it with `ReplacePart`. No need to use `Map`. Like so:

```
ReplacePart[lst, {i_, j_} :> lst[[i, j, 2]]]
```

> ```
> {{1.91901 + 0.0629745061 I, 1.9189 + 0.063 I, 1.99 + 0.063 I, 1.89 + 0.3 I}, 
>  {1.91 + 0.062974 I, 1.89 + 0.63 I, 1.9191 + 0.05061 I}}
> ```

Comment: I ran some `AbsoluteTiming` experiments using this method and Alexei's. I found on my sample list Alexei's method took around 950 seconds, but `ReplacePart` didn't finish running even after letting it run for around a day. Are there some limitation with the `ReplacePart` method to be aware of?

Comment: @math. I don't have any idea why `ReplacePart` is running so slowly on your system. You don't describe your test in sufficient detail. I timed my code on this array: `data = With[{rows = 1000, cols = 1000}, RandomComplex[1 + I, {rows, cols, 2}]];` and it completed in 2.3 sec. That seems pretty fact to me.

Answer (score 1):

Just this,

```
l //. {a___, {b_, c_}, d___} :> {a, c, d}
```

Where `l` is your list.